# How to iterate over columns, with similar names, and check whether they are equal?

Tags: python, pandas

This question is a follow-up to a similar one I posted a few days ago.

I have a data frame -- example shown below -- containing columns with similar names: 'Agreement Date', 'Agreement Date_x', etc. I am trying to figure out how to check whether my columns match up, and then create a new yes/no column if they do or do not match up.

| Contract ID | Agreement Date | Agreement Date_x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 05/04/1997 | 05/04/1997 |
| 1 | 03/02/1997 | 03/04/1997 |
| 2 | 05/07/2020 | 05/06/2021 |

Note: my actual dataset contains a dozen 'Agreement Date' columns

Many thanks :)

Comment: You can try using `np.where(condition, A, B)`

Comment: By match up do you mean if the column names are equal to partially match?

Comment: `d['a'].eq(df['a_x']).map({True:'yes', False:'no'})`

Comment: @ansev "*Note: my actual dataset contains a dozen 'Agreement Date' columns*" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could filter on the leading name and count if the value is unique:

```
df['match'] = df.filter(regex='^Agreement Date').nunique(axis=1).eq(1)
```

output:

```
   Contract ID Agreement Date Agreement Date_x  match
0            0     05/04/1997       05/04/1997   True
1            1     03/02/1997       03/04/1997  False
2            2     05/07/2020       05/06/2021  False
```

as yes/no:

```
import numpy as np
df['match'] = np.where(df.filter(regex='^Agreement Date').nunique(axis=1).eq(1), 'yes', 'no')
```

output:

```
   Contract ID Agreement Date Agreement Date_x match
0            0     05/04/1997       05/04/1997   yes
1            1     03/02/1997       03/04/1997    no
2            2     05/07/2020       05/06/2021    no
```